# Title of book where technology isn’t trusted and people who can memorise large amounts of data are special

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to remember title of book where technology isn’t trusted and people who can memorise large amounts of data are special because they are the only safe means to store and/or communicate information. There are two opposing syndicates one of which is called symbiots or similar.

"Mentats" sounds like a pretty similar idea, but it’s not *Dune*. I read it about 5 years ago, but I remember the description of technology seemed pretty dated and it may well have been written as long ago as the 80s.

I also don't think it was *Johnny Mnemonic*.

Comment: Mentats?  *Dune*?  If you can, please add more detail, any other plot or character beats, or when you read the book.  Anything you remember may be helpful.

Comment: Mentat sounds like a pretty similar idea, but it’s not Dune. I read it about 5 years ago, but I remember the description of technology seemed pretty dated and it may well have been written as long ago as the 80s.

Comment: From personal experience, it’s called a PhD in Chemistry.

Comment: If I remember right part of the plot is that although the two syndicates are enemies the agents/members are more like each other than they are like other people. Even to the point where both the syndicates are controlled by a single person or group.

Comment: William Gibson story "Johnny Mnemonic" perhaps?

Comment: @Danny3414 Granted I've only seen the movie version of Johnny Mnemonic, so there may be differences, but I seem to recall them being *reliant* on technology, not afraid of it.

Comment: Not Johnny Mnemonic I’m afraid. It’s pretty hazzy, but wiIl see if I can remember more of the plot.